# Code modification to copy all data in a row or the whole row instead of only copying a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

New VBA user here, the below code matches the 1st column in a worksheet with the 1st column in another worksheet using vlookup then copies the first cell from 1st to 2nd as the screenshots.

[image]
[image: 2]

**Code**

```
Sub solution()

Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim lrow_output As Integer  'variable indicating last fulfilled row
Dim WB_Input As Workbook
Dim WB_Output As Workbook
Dim WS_Input As Worksheet
Dim WS_Output As Worksheet
Dim funcStr As String

Set WB_Input = Workbooks("input")
Set WB_Output = Workbooks("output1")

Set WS_Input = WB_Input.Worksheets("input")
Set WS_Output = WB_Output.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS_Output
    lrow_output = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With WS_Input
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(2)).Address & ",2,0),"""")"
End With


With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, 2).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

**Problem**: I need the code to copy and paste the all data in the row, not just the first cell.

**Problem2**:If possible I need the code to scan multiple sheets, not just one so it would be 1 input main workbook sheet and 4 output sheets in the output workbook.

**Problem3**(Optional): if possible I need the successfully matched and copied rows in the input workbook to be colored to tell them from the unsuccessful matches.

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate all the possible aid.

Comment: What code have you ttried, what problems did you encounter.  SO is not a code writing service, you have to show what you tried.

Comment: I apologize, I spent a lot of time trying to breakdown and study the code above so I can modify it but I failed, if you have the solution kindly give me just a tip and i will do the rest myself

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick macro that will take the active cell row copy it and then select specified sheet and paste it in active cell row:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
'
' CopyPaste Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet#").Select
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I need to implement that in my original code that will automatically compare the 2 sheets then copy paste matched rows when found , your method would require me to manually match them myself